# Wrong to build java application that uses OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, static-libraries, executable-jar, opencv3.0

I built the executable file jar that uses opencv in eclipse, but when i tried to run it using

> java -jar Test.jar

I got:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path

Then, i tried build it using Ant. but when I tried to run it, I got another exception:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core

Obs: I built opencv3 as static library.
I want to make jar file that will run independent, if the computer has opencv installed.

Comment: In order to use opencv with java it needs to be a dynamic library and you need to add `-djava.library.path=` *directory with opencv_java300.dll*  before the `-jar`.

Comment: You also need to build the opencv jar and have that on the classpath.